# How should I go about writing a JavaScript plugin API in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, api, plugins

I'm doing a project in Ruby, and I want to be able to write plugins for it in JavaScript, so I'm working on a JavaScript API for it. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an existing javascript interpreter, like [`therubyracer`](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer). You can eval the plugin code and interact with it through that.